# Not able to disable DateTime picker created Dynamically

Tags: jquery, html, asp.net-mvc-4, knockout.js

I have a scenario where I am creating controls on the page dynamically based on user settings(using JQuery), so when user set a particular control as Read-Only then the controls has to be disabled, currently I am not able to achieve this read-only for DateTime picker, as I am creating the control dynamically. I am using MVC and knockout. Any suggestions would be of great help.
Thanks in Advance

Comment: please share some relevant code (HTML, jQuery etc)

Comment: @BhushanKawadkar : I can't share complete code but a bit I can share, below is the dataBindValue used dataBindValue = 'data-bind="value:Value,disable: $root.IsReadonly() == true,attr: {title: ValidationMessage },css: {\'validation-failed\': ValidationStatus() ==\'ERROR\', \'validation-warning\': ValidationStatus() ==\'WARNING\'}"';

Comment: please share it on jsfiddle. I will update post for you from jsfiddle